# Java DecimalFormat

Tags: java, math, double, decimal

```
 DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double zipf = 0.23951367781155017; 
String zipt = df2.format(zipf);
System.out.println(zipt);
```

And I get "0,24"

The problem with this is then I want to use it as a double. But the Double.valueOf(); method fails due to the comma being there in the string output. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Since you are casting to a `String` anyhow, you could always use `String.format("%.2d", zipf);`

Comment: or just replace the comma sign in string with a dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decimal dot, you should create an instance with english locale like this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String zipt = nf.format(zipf);
System.out.println(zipt);
```

I also suggest setting rounding to HALF_UP, because default rounding is not what most of us would expect: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN

```
nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different locale.German has dot

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
```

Alternative woud be to use string and then modify string to your needs.After that just parse to double.All done :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problems is the local that your JVM is using , try to change at your current local.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) constructor that allows you to specify locale

`new DecimalFormat("#.##", new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("en")));`

Answer (score 0):

you could "format" your double manually but cutting of the decimal places like this:

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double zipf = 0.23951367781155017;
String zipt = df2.format(zipf);
System.out.println(zipt);

long zipfLong = Math.round(zipf*100);
double zipfDouble = zipfLong/100.0;
System.out.println(zipfDouble);
```

with Math.round you make sure the that 0.239.. becomes 0.24. `zipf*100` will "cut" off the additional decimal places and `zipfLong/100.0` will add the decimal places again. Sorry, bad explanation but here is the output:

```
0,24
0.24
```

And you can reuse the new `zipfDouble` as a `double` value without casting or taking care of `locale` settings.