# java String formatting up to two decimal places with a char

Tags: java, string, format

So I'm having a trouble formatting a String.

My output should always be `##.##C or F` (temperature conversion)

so here is my method:

```
public void setResultLabel(double inNumber, char inChar)
{   

    String number, letter;

    number = String.valueOf(inNumber);

    letter = String.valueOf(inChar);

    String temp;

    temp = number + letter;

    String format = String.format("%2.5s", temp); /* how do you make this code 
    so that the out put result will always be up to two decimal places 
    with a char C or F? */

    result.setText(format);

    add(result);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995817/java-decimalformat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setResultLabel(double inNumber, char inChar)
{   

    String number, letter;
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.##"+inChar);


    String formated = decimalFormat.format(inNumber); 
    /* formated  is your result  */
    // System.out.println(formated);

    result.setText(format);
    add(result);
}
```

Comment: glad  to know it helped. @corkiiunranked

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) to format decimal numbers. To change the decimal mark from a "," to a "." (if needed), use `DecimalFormatSymbols`

```
public void setResultLabel(double inNumber, char inChar) {   
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

    result.setText(df.format(inNumber) + inChar);
    add(result);
}
```

Note that usually `DecimalFormat` would be a field in your class since you don't want to create a new `DecimalFormat` and a new `DecimalFormatSymbols` every time you call the `setResultLabel()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result using following code snippet.

```
double p =10.1234;
char s = 'F';
String formatted = String.format("%.2f%S", p, s);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

You can find more information about formatting at [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). Note that there are other alternatives as well to achieve the output, you can find the useful links [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).